# Magento 2.3.2 : Paypal Credit method not displaying in checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, upgrade

I have to upgrade magento2.2.0 to magento2.3.2. in old version PayPal credit payment displaying & working fine but upgrade version 2.3.2 is not displaying in checkout.

shipping step to payment step pass 3 methods but payment step in displaying only two.

Ref link - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22525

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you linked clearly says that PayPal Credit has been removed and instead is now part of the Express Checkout for applicable countries & merchants (see [this commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d0a5ba4491d2cc34e2f23cf407304516e50b7b5e) for instance).

If you go through the PayPal Express Checkout you should see PayPal Credit as an option provided your account has it.

Comment: Removed? I already checked with Express checkout not displaying still

Comment: It's removed? then why it's coming in shipping information step api?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: The commit that you linked to only removed the option from the configuration. It does not remove the PayPal Credit button from the checkout page.